# MYSQL - WHERE IN (SELECT...) - Limit results to one per subquery match

Tags: mysql

I'm using a subquery to return find the STOCK_CODE of any products sold but now out of stock. I then uses this subquery to Select alternative products with a matching STOCK_CODE (If I sell out of Brand A Beans I want to be able to show that Brand B is still in stock - both would share the Stock_code "Beans")

My query works but returns ALL matching alternative products (Brand B,C & D) - I want to be able to limit the returned rows to 1 per STOCK_CODE (which I can do using GROUP BY STOCK_CODE) but I also want that row be the product last delivered longest ago (for perishable products and generate stock rotation).

So far my Query is:

```
SELECT p.PRODUCT_ID
     , s.SUPP_CODE
     , p.STOCK_CODE
     , p.DATE_LDELIV 
  FROM product p  
  JOIN supplier_code s  
    on s.PROD_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID  
   AND MAINSUPP = 1
 WHERE p.STOCK_CODE IN   
  (SELECT p.STOCK_CODE 
     FROM product p 
     JOIN replen r 
       ON p.PRODUCT_ID = r.PROD_ID 
    WHERE p.STOCK_QTY <= 0) 
   AND p.STOCK_QTY > 0
```

Which will return something like this:

```
PRODUCT_ID  SUPP_CODE   STOCK_CODE              DATE_LDELIV     
68561       FEW         BULB LED GLS BC 810LM   2020-01-16
73541       FEW         BULB LED GLS BC 810LM   2018-10-17
71274       FEW         BULB LED GLS BC 810LM   2017-11-29
73630       REGATTA     MACKSON L               0000-00-00
```

What I need is to restrict the rows to one match per subquery results AND to choose the EARLIEST DATE_LDELIV.
Desired Return:

```
PRODUCT_ID  SUPP_CODE   STOCK_CODE              DATE_LDELIV     
71274       FEW         BULB LED GLS BC 810LM   2017-11-29
73630       REGATTA     MACKSON L               0000-00-00
```

I've tried using "GROUP BY STOCK_CODE" but I don't know how it choose whihc rows to discard. Either way it returns PRODUCT_ID 68561 and I can't ORDER BY before hand!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: 2 solutions possible : something like `\`DATE_LDELIV\`=MIN(\`DATE_LDELIV\`)` in the WHERE at the end , or `ORDER by \`DATE_LDELIV\` LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much with subquerys and MySQL, so the syntax might be a little off.

```
SELECT p.PRODUCT_ID, s.SUPP_CODE, p.STOCK_CODE, p.DATE_LDELIV 
FROM supplier_code s
JOIN product p
    ON p.product_id = (SELECT innerp.product_id
                       FROM product innerp
                       WHERE innerp.product_id = s.prod_id
                       AND p.stock_qty > 0
                       ORDER BY innerp.date_ldeliv ASC
                       LIMIT 1)
WHERE p.STOCK_CODE IN   
  (SELECT p.STOCK_CODE 
     FROM product p 
     JOIN replen r 
       ON p.PRODUCT_ID = r.PROD_ID 
    WHERE p.STOCK_QTY <= 0) 
WHERE s.MAINSUPP = 1
```